# user input values are not added to hashmap

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a hashmap which has pre entered values, and I am taking more values from the user. Then those values get sorted to the ascending order. But in this code user entered values not get inserted to the hashmap.

```
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CFG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     

        sortByValueJava8Stream();
    }

    private static void sortByValueJava8Stream()
    {
        Map<String, Integer> unSortedMap = getUnSortedMap();
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        unSortedMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

        System.out.println("Sorted Map   : " + sortedMap);


    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> getUnSortedMap() {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        HashMap<String, Integer> unsortMap = new HashMap<>();
        unsortMap.put("Shiran", 342);
        unsortMap.put("Hashini", 448);
        unsortMap.put("Chanchala", 398);
        unsortMap.put("Priyankara", 399);
        unsortMap.put("Mayuri", 350);
        unsortMap.put("Sameera", 321);
        unsortMap.put("Supun", 299);
        unsortMap.put("Supuni", 378);
        unsortMap.put("Kavindu", 384);
        unsortMap.put("Nadeeka", 440);

        System.out.println("Do you want to add more players? ");
        System.out.println("if yes pres 1 : ");
        Integer c = in.nextInt();
        if (c == 1) {
            addUser();

        } return unsortMap;
    }


    public static void addUser(){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String, Integer> unsortMap = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("Enter name : ");
        String a = in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Time : ");
        Integer b =in.nextInt();
        unsortMap.put(a,b);

    }

}
```

---

I have created a method called adduser() and I called it to add the new values. but data not get entered by it. How I can fix this ?

Comment: The `unsortMap` in your `addUser()` is not the same map as the `unsortMap` in your `getUnSortedMap()`. You create a new method local scope map, that has nothing to do with the other map.

Comment: Add user is just creating a new map whose value get lost when the function is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is globally declaring *unsortMap* Map so that it can be used in other methods.
The issue is with your `addUser` method as it creates a local `unsortMap` which is never used after completion of the function.
Another way is to pass the *unsortMap* Map as a parameter to the `addUser` method and put the required pair.

Following is the modified working code.

```
class CFG
{
    static Map<String, Integer> unsortMap; // global declaration of Map
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        sortByValueJava8Stream();
    }
    private static void sortByValueJava8Stream()
    {
        Map<String, Integer>unSortedMap = getUnSortedMap();
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        unSortedMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

        System.out.println("Sorted Map   : " + sortedMap);
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> getUnSortedMap()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        unsortMap = new HashMap<>(); // Initializing the Map
        unsortMap.put("Shiran", 342);unsortMap.put("Hashini", 448);
        unsortMap.put("Chanchala", 398);unsortMap.put("Priyankara", 399);
        unsortMap.put("Mayuri", 350);unsortMap.put("Sameera", 321);
        unsortMap.put("Supun", 299);unsortMap.put("Supuni", 378);
        unsortMap.put("Kavindu", 384);unsortMap.put("Nadeeka", 440);

        System.out.println("Do you want to add more players? ");
        System.out.println("if yes pres 1 : ");
        Integer c = in.nextInt();
        if (c == 1)
            addUser();
        return unsortMap;
    }
    public static void addUser()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name : ");
        String a = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Time : ");
        int b = in.nextInt();
        unsortMap.put(a,b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass **unSortedMap** to **addUser** method.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getUnSortedMap() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, Integer> unsortMap = new HashMap<>();
    unsortMap.put("Shiran", 342);
    unsortMap.put("Hashini", 448);
    unsortMap.put("Chanchala", 398);
    unsortMap.put("Priyankara", 399);
    unsortMap.put("Mayuri", 350);
    unsortMap.put("Sameera", 321);
    unsortMap.put("Supun", 299);
    unsortMap.put("Supuni", 378);
    unsortMap.put("Kavindu", 384);
    unsortMap.put("Nadeeka", 440);

    System.out.println("Do you want to add more players? ");
    System.out.println("if yes pres 1 : ");
    Integer c = in.nextInt();
    if (c == 1) {
        addUser(unsortMap);

    } return unsortMap;
}


public static void addUser(Map<String, Integer> unsortMap){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name : ");
    String a = in.nextLine();
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Time : ");
    Integer b =in.nextInt();
    unsortMap.put(a,b);

}
```